# Configure instance before injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Adding windows service support in `Main` method of console project:

```cs
var myVariable = "example";
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
}).UseWindowsService().Build().Run();
```

Worker class:

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
....
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // Need to use myVariable here
    }
}
```

How to pass `myVariable` to worker class instance?

Comment: use [IOptions<TOption>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have misunderstood please let me know, but if your worker had the appropriate constructor defined:

```
public class Worker : IWorker 
{
     private readonly string example = String.Empty;
     public Worker(string example) => this.example = example;

     ...
}
```

When you do your dependency injection you would do something along these lines:

```
var example = "Passed?";
services.AddSingleton<IWorker>(configure => new Worker(passed));
```

I believe that is what you are inquiring.